# Use default value of field when null is passed in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

How can I configure a field/serializer with Jackson to handle a case when there is a default value for primitive field and `null` is set in JSON. As a result I expect that default values is used instead of `null`.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public static class Wrapper {
    private boolean value = true;
}
```

When JSON `{"value": null}` is used with `null` I expect that default(`true`) value will be used. It does not work as expected and `false` is assigned to `value`.

Comment: If your schema has `value` as nullable, why not make the class field a `Boolean`? That way, you can write your getter and setter to handle the default value's logic.

Comment: My schema does not support nullable value for the field but users of API can sometime send it